# ¿cómo debuguear en PHP?

Tags: php

Como explico en el título de la pregunta mi problema básicamente es de qué manera puedo debuguear una aplicación php la cual es usada como backend para una aplicación Android, ya que no conozco la manera de hacerlo, he probado con lo típico:

```
 $name = $jsonencode[0]->nombre;
 echo '<pre>'; var_dump($name); echo '</pre>';
 die();
```

Pero no me ha dado resultado, si alguien conoce una manera mejor lo agradecería, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Porque no te ha dado resultado? Si no tiene valor deberías revisar primero porque no se obtiene el valor.

Comment: Sigue el rastro del valor que buscas, en algún lugar debe comenzar. Si `$jsonencode[0]->nombre` no da resultado, prueba con `$jsonencode`. Si no encuentras lo que esperabas, busca donde se le asigna valor a `$jsonencode` y así sucesivamente...

Comment: Al final lo que mejor me ha ido ha sido un programa llamado Postman, lo dejo aquí por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda, gracias a los demás por dejar vuestros comentarios, un saludo.    https://www.getpostman.com/